# Error al pasar a produccion en angular

Tags: angular

Buenas tardes les comento mi error, estoy probando subiendo una pagina desarrollada en angular a mi hosting, resulta que solo funciona bien si llamo a la pagina de esta forma (esta pagina cuenta con servicios para obtener datos de una DB)

```
http://mipagina.com
```

Ahora, al momento de llamar a la pagina de las siguientes maneras

```
https://mipagina.com
www.mipagina.com
```

Al ingresar de esta forma los servicios dejan de funcionar ósea somo me trae un template sin nada de información de la DB

Estoy atento a cualquier ayuda, desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo

Update:

```
Logre solucionarlo agregando en mi backend hecho con php las siguientes lineas (no era un problema del angular sino que era mi back-end)

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: seguramente sea cors, las tres urls son diferentes

Comment: Que comando utilizas para crear el build de producción?

Comment: @aloMalbarez Efectivamente mi error era con los CORS, estaba creando un back en php y necesesitaba agregar unos headers para que funcionara correctamente